# QtMultimedia module in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: qt4

I have some problems with the QtMultimedia module in Ubuntu 12.04. I can't find its development files in `/usr/include`. Should I install extra packages for this? If yes, what is its name?

Note: I have installed QtSDK from Ubuntu packages, not the SDK provided by Nokia.

Comment: @hyde Could you explain better what your question is, do you want to reward the existing answer or the existing answer is deprecated?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to reward the existing answer, it is still valid, and contained all the information needed to get some old code for old Ubuntu to build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been having the same problem, which I just solved. It seems that the QtMultimedia module now resides in the QtMobility package. So you need to install QtMobility, which provides QtMultimediaKit :

```
sudo apt-get install qtmobility-dev
```

When compiling, you must add the following flags :

```
-I/usr/include/QtMultimediaKit -I/usr/include/QtMobility
-lQtMultimediaKit
```