# QtMultimedia inclusion in Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, qt

I am using QtMultimedia module in my application. However, the following code, which passes in Windows, fails on ubuntu.

```
 #include <QtMultimedia/QAbstractVideoSurface>
 #include <QtMultimedia/QVideoFrame>
```

according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392604/qtmultimedia-module-in-ubuntu-12-04lts), QtMultimediaKit must be installed. However, the location of headers differ, and code that passes looks like:

```
 #include <QtMultimediaKit/QAbstractVideoSurface>
 #include <QtMultimediaKit/QVideoFrame>
```

It is admittedly a minor difference, but it prevents me from interchangeably compiling in Windows and ubuntu. My guess is, i should use some form of macro expression, in lines of:

```
#ifdef WIN_MACRO
     #include <QtMultimedia/QAbstractVideoSurface>
     #include <QtMultimedia/QVideoFrame>
#else
     #include <QtMultimediaKit/QAbstractVideoSurface>
     #include <QtMultimediaKit/QVideoFrame>
#endif
```

to make the code compile on both systems. If that is correct, what should the macro be? If not - how can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a macro in the Qt libraries that should help you. Try:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
```